# Defining functions dynamically does not work inside class objects?

Tags: python, function, class, oop

In my current project, I am constructing functions dynamically by assembling a string, executing this string, then appending the resulting functions to a list. This works well inside a console, even when looped, but strangely does not work when I attempt to do the same thing inside a class object. Do you know why, and how I could get this to work?

The example snippet below is a minimal example. Constructing a function from a string is not an issue inside the main script, but when used inside a class object, the function is no longer assembled and an attempt to append it to a list returns an error.

```
import numpy as np

# Create a string for a function
funstr  = "def fun1(x): return x"

# Create a function
exec(funstr)

# Call the function
print('Evaluate the function:')
print(fun1(5))
print('Success!')

# Create functions in a loop
funlist = []
for i in range(5):
    funstr  = "def fun2(x): return x+"+str(i)
    exec(funstr)
    funlist.append(fun2)

# Check if the stored functions work
print('Evaluate the list functions:')
for i in range(5):
    print(funlist[i](5))
print('Success!')

# Try the same thing in a class
class testobject:
    
    def build_functions(self):
        
        # Do the same thing we did outside inside the class
        self.funlist = []
        for i in range(5):
            funstr  = "def fun3(x): return x+"+str(i)
            exec(funstr)
            print("Here, a function fun3 should have been assembled. For some reason, it hasn't been.")
            # !! Here, the function crashes because 'fun3' does not exist. !!
            self.funlist.append(fun3)
            
        print('Evaluate the list functions inside the object:')
        for i in range(5):
            print(self.funlist[i](5))
            
# Initialize an object
obj     = testobject()

# Create the functions inside
obj.build_functions()
```

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using `lambda`?

Comment: Why on earth are you using `exec`?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Barmer: Because in my actual example, the functions are a lot more complicated and consist of multiple lines. Compressing the actual functions indo inline variants is a lot more complex.

Comment: @Barmer: The error is "NameError: name 'fun3' is not defined".

Comment: I suspect the problem is that `exec()` is defining the function in the local scope. But since the compiler doesn't see any assignment of `fun3` in the code, it's looking for the variable in the global scope.

Comment: @MattDMo: Is there an option to create functions from a string without exec?

Comment: @J.Galt If not lambda, then use a closure. Defining the function from a string is the basic problem, try to find a better way.

Comment: The initial question is, why do you need to create functions from strings?

Comment: @Barmar: I don't think it's a compiler issue. If you run the code, everything runs fine right up until the line where I attempt to append fun3.

Comment: When you run a Python script, it first compiles the code.

Comment: I need to construct functions from strings because I have a number of keyworks and options which define how I assemble the function I actually want to evaluate (polynomial basses with different numbers of parameters, orders, and polynomial types). By far the easiest way to handle is is to assemble these functions as a string.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with class objects. I get the same problem if I use similar code in an ordinary function.

Comment: `def build_function(i):
    funstr  = "def fun3(x): return x+"+str(i)
    exec(funstr)
    print(fun3(5))`

Comment: @Barmar: Oh, interesting! Hmm.

Comment: `exec` doesn't modify local scopes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fun3` is being defined in the local scope, but `self.funlist.append(fun3)` is looking for the variable `fun3` in the global scope (because there's no local variable definition visible in the source code of the function).

You can use the `locals()` function to get a dictionary of the local variables.

```
self.funlist.append(locals()['fun3'])
```